# Appending mysql data to bootstrap website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

So i have a mysql database with youtube src links in it. The purpose of this is that video's will appear on a page based on a id in the url.

So for example:

when the url has ?id=1 it has to load all video's in the database with the id 1. I have a made a api that does the following:

```
<?php
include 'db.inc.php';
$vak = $_GET["vak"];

$sql= "select c.video from content c JOIN vakken v ON v.naam = c.naam where c.naam = '$vak' ";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if($result)
  {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $video[] = $row;

    }
    $jsonresult =  json_encode($video);
  //  print $jsonresult;
    return $jsonresult;
  }
  else{
    echo 'no result';

  }

?>
```

The json looks as follows:

> [
>           {
>               "video": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ggXtleNDP8"
>           },
>           {
>               "video": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ggXtleNDP8"
>           },
>           {
>               "video": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ggXtleNDP8"
>            },
>           {
>               "video": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ggXtleNDP8"
>           }
>       ]

How do i echo this in a embedded video in a bootstrap site? I tried jquery but it did not work for me

Comment: I think you are a little bit confused....where you print that json? On the page? Bootstrap is a framework, but it doesn't embed videos for you. You need to get that json on the front end (with javascript, or jquery, or something else) and print the html to embed the video. However, the result you want to achieve can be done server side (and you don't need a json, you can simply echo the html) or client side (with javascript, in this case is not strictly necessary that you return a json)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: Ty for the feedback. Can you provide code how to display it on the page? When I echo nothing happens and how do I do that in a div? Sorry my English is not the best. I understand bootstrap and understand what it does and what not.